# Match time in perl +1 minute?

Tags: regex, perl, time

I have the following code where I'm reading in time values and will compare against current time values. The time format that is being pulled is hh:mm:ss, the time format that I'm comparing to is hh:mm.  Right now I have it so that if $flow has the value of 00:14:09 in it, $time will only match if it has 00:14.  I'd like it to also match if it's +1 minutes beyond, such as if the $flow value was 00:15:35.  Could someone help me with how to make this work?

Thanks.

```
if ($flow[$flow_count] =~ /$time[$count]/)
```

Sample data:

```
$flow[0] = Dec 2 00:15:35 some data
$time[0] = 00:14
```

Comment: Calculate `(hours * 360) + (minutes * 60) + seconds` for both read time and current time. If `abs (read time - current time) < 60` they are less than a minute apart. [Hint: using a regex is not the way to go here.]

Comment: No year in your timestamp?

Comment: Sometimes, 3:00:30 is a minute after 1:59:30. You'd need to know the year and time zone to handle that. ("local" is good enough for the second requirement.) // Sometimes, 1:00:30 is a minute after 1:59:30, you'd need to know the year and the time zone to handle that. ("local" isn't good enough for the second requirement.)

Comment: @ikegami pick any year? :) Wonder how to abuse `Time::Piece` in such way.

Comment: what if I read in hh:mm:ss like Vicky suggested? I should have enough info then, right?

Comment: BTW, it's all in 24hour time

Comment: @cycloxr, No, because of DST. Sometimes 3:00:30 is a minute after 1:59:30, sometimes it's 61 minutes. You need more information to know which.

Comment: It seems that OP could live with that.

Comment: @mpapec, Where do you see that?

Comment: yes, I could deal with that for now, chances of it happening is only twice per year

Comment: @ikegami I'm guessing, but we can wait and see his feelings about this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what if your data were:

`$flow[0] = Dec 2 00:00:14 some data`

you would have a false positive

One possible solution

```
$time[$count]=~/\d{2}\:(\d{2})/;
($min,$hour)=$2,$1;
$flow[$flow_count] =~/(\d{2})\:(\d{2})\:\d{2}/;
if ( ( $1==$hour && ($2==$min || $2==$min+1) ) || ($1==$hour+1 && $2==00 && $min==59  ) )
```

Comment: hmm, I'll have to play with this. I'll accept it once I can get it working with my code. Thanks.

Comment: You don't check the hours

Answer (score 0):

As has already been said, without year or timezone information, this type of test can not conclusively be done.  There will be exceptions along DST boundaries where things will fail to match.

However, if that's not a concern of yours, then using [`Time::Piece`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) and [`Time::Seconds`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Seconds.html) can do this fairly simply:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $str = 'Dec 2 00:15:35 some data';
my $test = '00:14';

my $time = Time::Piece->strptime("$test", "%H:%M");

my $time_re = join '|', map {($time + $_)->strftime("%H:%M:")} (0, ONE_MINUTE);

if ($str =~ $time_re) {
    print "Match found\n";

} else {
    print "Not a match\n";
}
```

*Note: Because we're only specifying a time, everything is being done as Jan 1 1970 UTC*